Source of a shita for when giving Tochacha (הוכח תוכיח) is likely to go unheeded
In a handwritten drasha written in 1904 by a relative, it refers to a peirush that offers a resolution for when the mitzva of הוכח תוכיח is conflicted with the need to avoid saying a דבר שאינו נשמע (a rebuke that will not be accepted).
Here is the excerpt (note the wording that I have outlined in red):

Where I have transcribed:

ופירוש הע"(?) ז"ל כי צריך המוכיח לעשות הבחנה בשנים או שלשה מצוות או
עבירות. היינו שמפעם ראשונה עד שלישית. אז אף אם אינו ידוע לו להמוכיח
שישמעו לו בכ"ז מצוה עליו להוכי[ח] אולי ישמעו לו, ואם יראה שבכל השלשה
פעמים אינם שמים על לב ולא ישמעו. אז להבא מצוה עליו שלא לומר

Meaning that one must try out the listener with tochacha on two or three mitzvos (with no number limit on repetitions of tochacha within each of the 2 or 3 mitzvos if the recipient refuses to listen) and if the person fails to heed the rebuke on each and every of these 2 or 3 mitzvos then we face a situation of a דבר שאינו נשמע and one would avoid giving tochacha regarding any additional mitzvos over and above the initial two or three.
Would anyone out there be familiar with: 1) position of this peirush; 2) what the roshei teivos stand for in the name of the peirush; 3) to whom does that refer; 4) in what sefer (and what page/daf/siman) can this be found?
Caveat is that the first roshei teivos within my own transcription הע"(?) ז"ל is merely a guess and might be misleading or inacurate and the letter after the ה might not be an ע.
Also I'm unsure whether the drasha is quoting a peirush or is merely paraphrasing the peirush.
For background on this issue see the gemaras in ערכין טז עמ' ב, ב"מ לא עמ' א which indicate the need to repeat a tochacha many times if the recipient refuses to listen in contrast with the gemara in יבמות סה עמ' ב which states:

וְאָמַר רַבִּי אִילְעָא מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר בְּרַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן:
כְּשֵׁם שֶׁמִּצְוָה עַל אָדָם לוֹמַר דָּבָר הַנִּשְׁמָע — כָּךְ
מִצְוָה עַל אָדָם שֶׁלֹּא לוֹמַר דָּבָר שֶׁאֵינוֹ נִשְׁמָע

I have looked in many places including meforshei shas in those sugyos and the meforshim on the Rambam in the 6th perek of הלכות דעות and in his Sefer HaMitzvos and in the Sefer HaChinuch (and many online resources) and have not been able to find such a position being mentioned.  There are meforshim who offer other solutions in resolving the conflict between הוכח תוכיח and דבר שאינו נשמע.
(my question is partially related to this, but I'm mainly looking to identify the source here)

alternatively, perhaps the intention of "היינו שמפעם ראשונה עד שלישית." is that he must try a total of three times, rebuking about 2 or 3 mitzvot or aveirot. this fits well with "ואם יראה שבכל השלשה פעמים אינם שמים על לב ולא ישמעו" at the end.

@Menachem - thanks. In the interim I posted this at https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=64692 and some variations on your thoughts are discussed during the back and forth. Still haven't identified the original מקור.
